# Is it bad if I update the UI with a separate thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a ListFragment which I update by running a separate thread that reads a file, then using that file it initializes a class and sends it to the UI thread. Is it okay or can it cause instability? What do they mean android isn't thread-safe? Is it better to use the AsyncTask thread instead of a normal thread?.

I switched the code to a separate thread and now the app sometimes crashes.

Here is the log -

```
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-395
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5010)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:964)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15438)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8599)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5651)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:750)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:720)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:812)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6720)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.TimedEventsListFragment.addToList(TimedEventsListFragment.java:88)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.ReadNWrite.rebuildList(ReadNWrite.java:66)
07-10 14:20:21.035: E/AndroidRuntime(11045):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.ReadNWrite.run(ReadNWrite.java:24)
```

Answer (score 3):

> android isn't thread-safe

is totally incorrect. Android is as thread-safe as any systems.

Using a separate thread to do long-running tasks is a perfectly good strategy, and in fact, [recommended](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction,
>   this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you
>   implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network
>   access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is
>   blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From
>   the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse,
>   if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5
>   seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous
>   "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide
>   to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.

What is not thread-safe is updating the UI from multiple threads:

> Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must
>   not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all
>   manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there
>   are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> 1. Do not block the UI thread
> 2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

I do not know of any GUI toolkit in any operating systems in which updating the GUI from multiple threads is sensible or safe.

Other than using threads directly, Android also support [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) to do long-running operation. AsyncTask uses threads, but makes it much more easier and convenient to use than the general-purpose thread mechanism.

Comment: There *are* multi-threaded toolkits, but gawd do they suck... It's a problem of lock propagation direction, user actions are orthogonal to program logic in that sense, hence deadlocks are inevitable, unless you lock on any action, which defeats multi-threading. +1 for the answer though, very sensible. I would also add that using executors is better in most cases, than just raw Threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RunOnUIThread if you know the Activity you need to update. e.g.:

```
Activity activity = (Activity)context;

 activity.RunOnUiThread(delegate
     {
        //ui code
      });
```

This is in Mono (C#), not java btw.

Comment: can this be written inside a class written in java or how do I this methode

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not if you use "normal thread" or "asynctask" but the fact that Android checks if you are updating an UI element from the UI thread or another thread and thrown an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not thread safe means that two threads can read a variable simultaneously, then one thread writes a new value and then the second thread overwrites that value based on an old, incomplete value.

Thread safety assures that the shared variable is only accessed by one thread at the time, and when one thread is done the next thread can gain access.

The problem with updating your UI with multiple threads is exactly this issue. One thread writes a value to a component, and another thread re-writes that value with based on an old, incorrect value. This can lead to the UI being unstable, and you cannot predict the output  values in your components (since different threads can be scheduled differently depending on OS etc).

Using a class that extends AsyncTask (that can be a private inner class in your Activity) is a better way. It performs some task in background and is designed to work closely to your Activity. However, launching several AsyncTasks will yield you the same problem as mentioned above.

As others have pointed out, you cannot access UI components directly from another thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the UI from multiple threads, either:

1. use the `AsyncTask` class for threaded operations
2. Implement a `Handler` in your `Activity` and pass it into the Threads